# Strange syntax error "unexpected unary+" related to a space after `+`

Tags: ruby

Given that `a` is undefined, the following looks fine:

```
a + b + blah
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

Removal of space seems to matter:

```
a + b +blah
# => syntax error, unexpected unary+, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

What does this mean, and why does this occur by just removing a space? Is `+` not treated normal here? If I define `a` and `b`, it becomes:

```
a, b = 1, 1
a + b +blah
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method `blah' for main:Object
```

where it again looks like `+` is treated correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unary `+@` operator is a valid one on its own (takes a single operand and returns its value - eg. `+4` returns `4`). Not to be confused with the addition operator `+` which works on two operands.

Also, it takes precedence over the normal `+` addition operator.

Hence, `+c` in `a + b +c` in `a + b +c` is getting parsed as the equivalent of `a + b c`, which is not valid, as Ruby is unable to determine whether the `+c` is a normal method argument `()` or block `{}`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Very well explained for this non obvious Ruby quirk!